# Test for comparing ratios of single tail distributions

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance

Suppose I have data that looks like this:

[image]

The infected numbers usually average around 4-10 in both the control and test. Let's call these values **A**. The total numbers can be anything between 20-90 in both the control and test. Let's call these values **B** The **null hypothesis** is always there is no difference between the Control and Test.

Initially, I used a t-test and my two columns of data were: (1) A for each sample in Control, (2) A for each sample in Test

However, I deemed this test invalid for my data because, the **A** values average close to 0 and as there are no negative numbers. It is no longer a normal distribution. **A** forms more of a single tailed normal distribution. (Please correct me if I may still use t-test with a single tailed distribution)

Then, I tried fisher's exact test with a 2x2 contingency table with the following parameters: (1st row) A, (2nd row) B - A, (1st column) control, (2nd column) test. However, the tables usually end up having numbers like 700-800 in the second row, and 5-15 in the first row. The data becomes skewed because of the large values in the 2nd row. The small difference in the first row come out as insignificant.

I looked into Barnard's exact test, but that doesn't seem any better than Fisher's exact test. I'm having a hard time in wrapping my mind around what things to compare to prove this properly, let alone choose a test that does so. For instance, should I be comparing the ratios, or the raw infected numbers, or take averages of ratios, etc. Part of the problem is the large variance I see in **B**(can be anything from ~20-~90). Hence, can someone offer some guidance on this issue.

Comment: You don't mention a hypothesis that I could see

Comment: @Glen_b I've updated the post. Please let me know if that clarifies things.

Comment: Null hypotheses relate to population parameters. "No difference" is not suitable as a hypothesis unless it's clear what kind of difference is intended. Presumably you should be treating the control and test figures as pairs of proportions, and making some hypothesis about how the proportions within the pairs relate.

Comment: Essentially, what I want to get at is, when the samples are treated with test, for certain experiments, we expect to see a "significant" variation. For other times, we don't expect to see a "significant" variation. But I'm unable to give a more specific hypothesis than this because the example is very generic. Is it something else you're getting at? @Glen_b

Comment: Let's leave that aside for the moment; I'll come at it from another direction. Can you say something about the 20 different samples - do you expect there could be variation in the proportion of infected controls across samples? Do those samples represent some notional random selection from a larger population of possible sets of samples or are they in some sense "fixed" (you have these samples because that's what its possible for anyone to get, for example)

Comment: These 20 samples are essentially trays of cultured bacteria. They were treated with different chemicals to see if a gene is expressed. So, yes, these samples represent some notional random selection. I do expect there to be variation in the proportions of infected controls across samples; however, I don't expect there to be much variation in the raw counts of infected. Because, often times, the infected number is 0. The proportion immediately becomes 0. The total counts vary anywhere from 20-90. Lastly, I expect there to be more infected when there are more total. Am I hitting the right spots?